# Underline still showing even though text decoration is set

Tags: css, text-decorations

Even though I have set text-decoration to none, an underline is still showing on the h1 element. If you want to see the full css, go [here](http://pastebin.com/rUVst9dL). I am new to css, and this is just an adapted version of some code I found on the internet, sorry if the problem is obvious. If the problem isn't with the bellow code (which is where I think it probably is) then I will add in other relevant code.

You can see the page this is working on [here](http://www.codebundle.net/)

```
#pagetop h1 , a:visited
{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    line-height:90px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:27px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    float:left;
    margin-left:23px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS selector `#pagetop h1 , a:visited` states that you would like to apply those styles to an `h1` and also an `a` in its visited state.

The comma in your code represents a list of separate selectors rather than a combined selector. In your case you don't need to separately specify the same styles for both the `h1` and the `a`.

What you want to select is an `a` that is a descendant of an `h1` within `#pagetop` (so that it isn't applied to all `h1`s):

```
#pagetop h1 a { text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed to do, will accept in a few mins when I can :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad it wasn't confusing :) Not sure if I explained it properly. Good luck!

Comment: Your explanation was great and I understand it a lot better now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is text decoration in your link in the h1 tag.
Add this style:

```
h1 a
{
text-decoration:none;
}
```